# Touch coordinates on mobile and desktop

Tags: mobile, touch, coordinates

I'm trying to create a spot the difference game that will work on desktop and mobile and am having problems finding the coordinates on the image the player touched when using a mobile.

The game is fluid on the mobile, so the images automatically resize to fill the available screen.

I'm using this code to detect mouse position:

```
$(document).on("click",".image-wrapper",function(e){
  var coordX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  var coordY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  alert (coordX + ', ' + coordY);
}
```

The code works great on desktop, but when I try it on mobile, it gives different results.

The image dimensions are 368px x 550px.

If I touch the image at the top, the coordinates I see are the same as the desktop.

However, if I touch half way down the image, the vertical coordinate shows about 60 pixels more than the desktop and if I touch at the bottom of the image, the vertical coordinate shows about 120 pixels more than the desktop.

Is there a way to get reliable coordinates on all devices?

My spot the difference game will be pretty useless otherwise :(